# Error while showing file from a url in google docs using android web view

Tags: android, webview

This is the error that i am getting when i am trying to view most of the file from a url|:-

I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(534)] "Uncaught Error: La`[object Object]", source: [https://www.gstatic.com/*/apps-viewer/*/js/k=apps-viewer.standalone.en_US.c6ywhKJMakY.O/m=main/rt=j/d=1/rs=AC2dHMI4zJ7puGF5q_sgbdM9VbNE4DOJ6g](https://www.gstatic.com/_/apps-viewer/_/js/k=apps-viewer.standalone.en_US.c6ywhKJMakY.O/m=main/rt=j/d=1/rs=AC2dHMI4zJ7puGF5q_sgbdM9VbNE4DOJ6g) (534)
06-14 16:51:26.332 29303-29303/com.sbi.fast I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(64)] "Uncaught #", source: [https://www.gstatic.com/*/apps-viewer/*/js/k=apps-viewer.standalone.en_US.c6ywhKJMakY.O/m=main/rt=j/d=1/rs=AC2dHMI4zJ7puGF5q_sgbdM9VbNE4DOJ6g](https://www.gstatic.com/_/apps-viewer/_/js/k=apps-viewer.standalone.en_US.c6ywhKJMakY.O/m=main/rt=j/d=1/rs=AC2dHMI4zJ7puGF5q_sgbdM9VbNE4DOJ6g) (64)

COde snippet:-

```
 webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //WebSettings.PluginState ps=
        //webView.getSettings().setPluginState();
        webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");





        /*/added later while retesting...*/
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.clearCache(false);


        if (!Utils.getInternetStatus(ProductLibFileDisplayActivity.this)) { // loading offline
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        }


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                // System.out.println("wbVw shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                //System.out.println("wbVw onLoadResource: " + countWebView);
                loadingVisibilityCount++;

                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProductLibFileDisplayActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    if (loadingVisibilityCount <= 3)
                        progressDialog.show();
                    else
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //  System.out.println("wbVw onPageFinished :" + countWebView);
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                    countWebView++;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                // System.out.println("wbVw onReceivedError error:" + error);
                //System.out.println("wbVw onReceivedError request:" + request);
            }
        });



        webView.loadUrl(googleDocLink);
```

Comment: any progress on it?

Comment: Yes akshay. Actually was with the local IP that on which files were hosted. Later I came to know that google docs can't access our local IP but after updating the url to release public one everything got solved.

Comment: That's great. You should post this as answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes akshay. Actually it was local IP that on which files were hosted. Later I came to know that google docs can't access our local IP but after updating the url to release public one everything got solved.

Comment: Hi, Could you be more specific on **after updating the url to release public**. I am also facing this problem on Android emulator. I want to know what I should do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Might help someone...

to update a google drive url follow the following steps:

1. Login to your Gmail Drive
2. Go to you file and Right Click it.
3. Click Share
4. Click Get sharable link seen on top right hand side
5. Under Link Sharing On Anyone on the Internet click 'can find and view'
6. Click More
7. Select the First Option On -Public on the Web (Anyone on the internet can find and access. No sign-in required)
8. Click Save Button
9. Then finally click Done.

This will make the link shareable to all users, thereby enabling everyone to open the file in the webview..

> Yes akshay. Actually it was local IP that on which files were hosted. Later I came to know that google docs can't access our local IP but after updating the url to release public one everything got solved.

This is what pravin in his answer probably meant when he said .. `after updating the url to release public`